# How to calculate covariance and correlation without using built in functions?

Tags: python

Write a function `check_independence` that for a given `distr_table` returns a named list with three values, where:

- First element `are_independent` is a boolean which states if `x` and `y` are independent `true` or `false`.
- Second element `cov` is the covariance between `x` and `y`.
- Third element `corr` is the correlation coefficient between `x` and `y`.

Note that you can’t use built-in functions cov and corr.

```py
distr_table  <-data.frame( X = rep(c(0,1), each =2),
    Y =rep(c(1,2), times = 2),
    Pr = c(0.3,0.25,0.15,0.3))
```

I am not sure how to finish my code..

```py
# calculates the Covariance matrix
def covMat(distr_table):
    # get the rows and cols
    rows, cols = distr_table.shape
    # the covariance matrix has a shape of n_features x n_features
    # n_featurs  = cols - 1 (not including the target column)
    cov = np.zeros((cols, cols))
    for i in range(cols):
        for j in range(cols):
            # store the value in the matrix
            cov[i][j] = calcCov(distr_table[:, i], distr_table[:, j])
            corr[i][j] = calcCov(x, y) / (x.std() * y.std())
    return cov, corr
```

Comment: You can find correlation and covariance definition here: https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs109/cs109.1178/lectureHandouts/150-covariance.pdf